# Retrieving Data from DynamoDB using AWSSDK.net (core version 3.3.5 and AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 version 3.3.1)

Tags: c#, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to retrieve the data from Dynamo DB based on a search criteria using Scan request. I am following the steps mentioned in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetScanning.html" page. My DynamoDB table contains more than 1 million records. I know that by using the do-while loop and ExclusiveStartKey  we can fetch the records from dynamo DB. but in my case I can not wait till search process is complete as this will hang my angularJS UI. instead I want to progressively load the data with out waiting for the search process to complete. How we can do that.?

sample request:

```
var lastEvaluatedKey = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>(); ;
    AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDbClient= new AmazonDynamoDBClient()
        var filterExpression = "#aws_s3_bucket = :v_aws_s3_bucket and contains(#aws_s3_key,:v_aws_s3_key)";
        var projectExpression = "#aws_s3_key,filename,#region,aws_s3_bucket,#projecttype,folder,#siteid,locationname,createdon,modifiedon";



        do
        {   
        var request = new ScanRequest
            {
                TableName = "Test1",
                ExclusiveStartKey=lastEvaluatedKey,

                FilterExpression = filterExpression,
                ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                              { "#region", "region" },
                              { "#siteid", "siteid" },
                              { "#projecttype", "projecttype" },
                              { "#aws_s3_key", "aws_s3_key" },
                              { "#aws_s3_bucket", "aws_s3_bucket" }                       
                            },
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
                            {":v_aws_s3_bucket", new AttributeValue { S =  "sampleBucket"}},
                            {":v_aws_s3_key", new AttributeValue { S =  "92226"}}
                            },

                ConsistentRead = true,
                ProjectionExpression = projectExpression
            };

        response = amazonDynamoDbClient.Scan(request); 
    lastEvaluatedKey = response.LastEvaluatedKey;}while(lastEvaluatedKey!=null && lastEvaluatedKey.count()!=0)
```

I tried executing the above request with out using do-while loop and saved the ExclusiveStartKey for the next request it throws error the  "The provided starting key is invalid: One or more parameter values were invalid: Null attribute value types must have the value of true".

any help on this issue will be helpful...

Comment: Where are you storing the lastEvaluatedKey? You need to get the key values from the stored object and set the start key values explicitly.

Comment: Sorry i missed this line my post Please find the details below.

from ScanReponse object, i am retrieving the last scanned key.
 lastEvaluatedKey = response.LastEvaluatedKey;

Comment: updated the logic to include lastEvaluatedKey  setting.

Comment: In problem statement, you have mentioned that you wanted to achieve without loop. Anyway, set the ExclusiveStartKey=lastEvaluatedKey for the second iteration. In the first iteration of the loop, the start key should not be set as it doesn't have any value. So it should be inside the conditional statement.

Comment: i tried removing the do while loop and execute the request, but i am receiving the below error for 2nd request. In UI, i got a search button.on click of that search button, i am recursively calling dynamoDB by passing the last evaluated key saved in session

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting appears to be because you're setting `ExclusiveStartKey` on the request without setting any values for its parameters. Notice how you aren't updating `request.ExclusiveStartKey` after you get your response. Obviously, if you don't do that, the scan won't know where to pick up again when you hit your limit. See below.

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDbClient= new AmazonDynamoDBClient()
var filterExpression = "#aws_s3_bucket = :v_aws_s3_bucket and contains(#aws_s3_key,:v_aws_s3_key)";
var projectExpression = "#aws_s3_key,filename,#region,aws_s3_bucket,#projecttype,folder,#siteid,locationname,createdon,modifiedon";
ScanRequest request = new ScanRequest
        {
            TableName = "Test1",
            FilterExpression = filterExpression,
            ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                          { "#region", "region" },
                          { "#siteid", "siteid" },
                          { "#projecttype", "projecttype" },
                          { "#aws_s3_key", "aws_s3_key" },
                          { "#aws_s3_bucket", "aws_s3_bucket" }                       
                        },
            ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
                        {":v_aws_s3_bucket", new AttributeValue { S =  "sampleBucket"}},
                        {":v_aws_s3_key", new AttributeValue { S =  "92226"}}
                        },

            ConsistentRead = true,
            ProjectionExpression = projectExpression
        };

    do
    {   
        response = amazonDynamoDbClient.Scan(request); 
        request.ExclusiveStartKey = response.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (response.lastEvaluatedKey.Count != 0);
```